# How to include a javascript file for IE8 browser only in meteor.js package?

Tags: meteor

I want to include a javascript file for IE8 browser only. Eg:

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
```

I am using following code in package.js for my meteor package:

```
Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.versionsFrom("METEOR@0.9.2.2");
  api.use('jquery');
  var path = Npm.require('path');
  var asset_path = path.join('js);
  // Surround following code in <!--[if lt IE 9]> and <![endif]--> tags somehow!!!!
  api.addFiles(path.join(asset_path, 'ie', 'html5shiv.js'), 'client');
}
```

I know that the final package will contain a minified version of all js files combined in one js file. In that case I would like to have the code look like:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    // Contents of html5shiv.js here!
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I propose, unfortunately I can't test it because I have no Windows environment available at the moment.

`my-package/client/views/lib/head.html`

```
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <meta name="lower-than-ie9">
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

`head` and `body` tags in Meteor Spacebars template syntax are treated specially : whatever you put between these tags (they can appear multiple times) will get appended to the final HTML document.

This is why we add this Meteor template piece of code to our package : if the IE version is lower than IE9, it will eventually create a meta tag with the name `lower-than-ie9`, which we can later on test presence or not.

`my-package/client/lib/my-package.js`

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  // search for the meta tag appended by the conditional inclusion comment
  if($("meta[name='lower-than-ie9']").length){
    // if it's there, load the script with jQuery
    $.getScript("/my-package/public/html5shiv.js");
  }
});
```

You will need to put the `html5shiv.js` script in the public directory of your package :

`my-package/public/html5shiv.js`

This is the structure of the package that you will need :

`my-package/package.js`

```
Package.onUse(function(api){
  api.versionsFrom("METEOR@0.9.2.2");
  api.use("jquery","client");
  api.addFiles([
    "client/views/lib/head.html",
    "client/lib/my-package.js"
  ],"client");
  // specify that the script is an asset to prevent it from
  // being minimized and bundled to the client
  api.addFiles("public/html5shiv.js","client",{
    isAsset:true
  });
});
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I was thinking if this could be done without polluting Meteor.startup func. Want my package to work out of the box. Maybe I should edit html5shiv.js and put all of its content in """if (!document.addEventListener) { //html5shiv.js content here!}""". What do you think?

Comment: Why not put the `script` tag directly in the head, within the conditional?